# Is it possible for an application to corrupt an entire filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, xfs

OS is Debian 10.

I was using Basilisk to install some old mac classic applications to a shared drive, ie "Unix Root", as the mac volume didn't have enough space.

When viewing the installed folder on the parent filesystem, it displayed as "xyz <?> (invalid encoding)"

Which got me thinking...is it possible for an application, running as a normal user, to corrupt an underlying filesystem, simply by trying to write to it in an unusual way? (I suppose it could effectively run rm on the entire mount point, but assume it's not doing anything "malicious" but rather "wrong")

What's a command I can run to verify filesystem integrity?

The actual parent filesystem I'm using is XFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A filename is a series of bytes. Different character encodings use those bytes to encode characters in different ways. As an extreme example UTF-16 uses 16 bits (two bytes) for each character but ISO-8859-1 uses only 8 bits (one byte) port character.

It's quite possible that the character encoding used by your Mac doesn't match the encoding expected by your server. The result is that filenames represented correctly on the Mac cannot be represented natively on the server, and so you get the error you described.

This hasn't corrupted the filesystem in the usual sense of the term (i.e. the filesystem structure is still intact, and the filenames and their data can be read in some way), but it has created filenames that are unusable on the server.

Comment: `filenames that are unusable` - I'd say "hard to use".